# Koszul complex of the cobar construction is acyclic

Tags: homological-algebra, operads, koszul-duality

This is a follow-up question on my question on math stackexchange (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4399553/proof-that-the-coaugmented-cobar-construction-of-a-cooperad-is-acyclic)

I think I have been able to come up with an answer on my own, but some details seem to not pan out correctly. Hopefully someone can help me figure it out.

I am trying to prove the unproven part of lemma 6.5.14 from the book *algebraic operads* from Loday-Vallette: the Koszul complex $C \circ_\iota \Omega C$ of the cobar construction $\Omega C$ on a coaugmented cooperad $C$ is acyclic. Remember that the twisting morphism $\iota$ is given as $\Omega C = T^c(s^{-1}\overline{C}) \twoheadrightarrow s^{-1} \overline{C} \longrightarrow C$.

The idea is to construct a homotopy $h$ on the complex as follows: for an element $(c; t_1,...,t_n)$ if $n \neq 1$, its image under $h$ is zero. Otherwise, we define $h(c;t) = \pm(\epsilon(c) c'; t_1',...,t'_{n'})$ where $s^{-1}c'$ is the root of $t$ and the tree $t$ decomposes as $s^{-1}c' \circ (t'_1, ...,t'_{n'})$. We aim to prove that $dh +hd = Id$.

It seems I come up with a problem when treating the case $(\eta;t)$ where $\eta$ denotes the coaugmentation:
$$dh(\eta;t) = \pm (dc'; t'_1,\ldots,t'_{n'}) \pm (c'; \ldots, dt'_i,\ldots)\pm \sum_i (c'_{(1)}; \ldots, c'_{(2)} \circ (t_i',\ldots,t_j'), \ldots) $$
and
\begin{align*}
hd(\eta; t) &= h ( \pm ( \eta; (d s^{-1}c') \circ (t'_1,\ldots,t'_{n'}) ) \pm (\eta; s^{-1}c' \circ (\ldots, dt_i',\ldots) ) \pm (\eta; (c'_{(1)} \circ_i c'_{(2)}) \circ (t'_1,\ldots,t'_{n'}) ) ) \\
&= \pm (dc'; t'_1,\ldots,t'_{n'}) \pm (c'; \ldots, dt'_i,\ldots)\pm \sum_i (c'_{(1)}; \ldots, c'_{(2)} \circ (t_i',\ldots,t_j'), \ldots) \end{align*}
Hence, my computation shows that $(dh+hd)(\eta;t) = 0$. The reason for this is that $d_\iota^r(\eta;t) = 0$ as $\Delta(\eta) = \eta \otimes \eta$ and when applying $\iota$ to the upper $\eta$, we obtain zero as $\eta$ is modded out in $\overline{C}$. How do I remedy this?

Comment: Look at the classical case of an operad supported in arity 1 ( = an associative algebra), which is easy and treated in many textbooks. Then think about how to generalize the argument in the most obvious way - it works.